# Filter list contained in entity returned by jpa/hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple jpa entity 'ApplicationForm' with a one to many list in it:

```
 @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy="textQuestion")
 private List<Dictionary> questions;
```

The variable Dictionary contained in ApplicationForm is just another plain entity with just the text of the question. 
The corresponding database table mapped by Dictionary is:

```
'locale' 'text'      'formId'
en       my question 123 
it       mia domanda 123
```

I was wondering if it's possible with jpa or hibernate, to build a query for retrieving an ApplicationForm entity with a Dictionary for a specific locale, for example 'it' only.
That would be easy enough to do with standard sql, but I cannot translate in hql.

If not possible, could you suggest an alternative way ? I have tried to manually iterate the  Dictionary questions list and remove the not required locale, but is not really elegant, and also I got a jpa/hibernate error.

I hope I made myself clear, and code supplied is enough.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I was wondering if it's possible with jpa or hibernate, to build a query for retrieving an ApplicationForm entity with a Dictionary for a specific locale, for example 'it' only.

Not with standard JPA. But Hibernate allows to apply arbitrary [filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-filters) to a collection load during a given session. From the Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide:

> #### [2.4.8. Filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-filters)
>
> Hibernate has the ability to apply
>   arbitrary filters on top of your data.
>   Those filters are applied at runtime
>   on a given session. First, you need to
>   define them.
>
> `@org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef`
>   or `@FilterDefs` define filter
>   definition(s) used by filter(s) using
>   the same name. A filter definition has
>   a `name()` and an array of
>   `parameters()`. A parameter will allow
>   you to adjust the behavior of the
>   filter at runtime. Each parameter is
>   defined by a `@ParamDef` which has a
>   name and a type. You can also define a
>   `defaultCondition()` parameter for a
>   given `@FilterDef` to set the default
>   condition to use when none are defined
>   in each individual `@Filter`. A
>   `@FilterDef`(s) can be defined at the
>   class or package level.
>
> We now need to define the SQL filter
>   clause applied to either the entity
>   load or the collection load. `@Filter`
>   is used and placed either on the
>   entity or the collection element
>
> ```
> @Entity
> @FilterDef(name="minLength", parameters=@ParamDef( name="minLength", type="integer" ) )
> @Filters( {
>     @Filter(name="betweenLength", condition=":minLength <= length and :maxLength >= length"),
>     @Filter(name="minLength", condition=":minLength <= length")
> } )
> public class Forest { ... }
> ```
>
> When the collection use an association
>   table as a relational representation,
>   you might want to apply the filter
>   condition to the association table
>   itself or to the target entity table.
>   To apply the constraint on the target
>   entity, use the regular `@Filter`
>   annotation. However, if you wan to
>   target the association table, use the
>   `@FilterJoinTable` annotation.
>
> ```
> @OneToMany
> @JoinTable
> //filter on the target entity table
> @Filter(name="betweenLength", condition=":minLength <= length and :maxLength >= length")
> //filter on the association table
> @FilterJoinTable(name="security", condition=":userlevel >= requredLevel")
> public Set<Forest> getForests() { ... }
> ```

#### See also

- [Chapter 17. Filtering data](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html) In the Hibernate Core Reference Documentation.
- [Hibernate3 Filters](http://relation.to/2002.lace)