# Filter JPA Entities without removing them from database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-initialization, hibernate-entitymanager

i have a database table "viewmodule" with a FK to itself (parent_id) to allow recursive structures.

```
CREATE TABLE viewmodule (
id,
type,
parent_id,
hide);
```

My Java application uses JPA/Hibernate to map the entities on that table. We have fixed entity hirachy which is solved by a @Discriminator annotation that uses the "type" column of the table.

```
public class ViewModule implements Serializable {
   private long id;
   private String type;
   private ViewModule parent;
   private Boolean hide;

   @OneToMany( targetEntity = ViewModule.class, cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent" )
   @Cascade( { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN } )
   private Set<ViewModules> children;
(...)
}
```

My task is now to load all elements from this table (in deep) but left out the ones which have the field "hide" set to true.
Its a apparently simple filter mechanism. My first approach was to use the Hibernate Filter annotation, which works well on the first layer (all viewmodules with parent_id = null). But the filter does not work on the "children" relation. (In my real life model, i have an inheritance structure for the different types of the ViewModules)

Therefore i've written a small function that recursively walks through the viewModule object tree and removes the viewModules from the children relation that have hide=true;

But, as all objects are still under observation of the jpa/hibernate entityManager, every remove from a collection is directly executed as delete in the database. So my filter function removes the entity from the database, and that is a bad thing.

I tried to use the "evict" method from the hibernate session to detach the entities before filtering but that leads to a LazyInitialisationException.

So, to prevent cloning all of my object my question is how to solve this problem? Is there a way to detach the object in way that all collections are initialized? Or is there a special Kung-Fu Chuck-Norris JPA Annotation that can filter the collections?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use native query

```
em.createNativeQuery("select * from viewmodule where hide = false", ViewModule.class).getResultList();
```

This works: [Filter list contained in entity returned by jpa/hibernate query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300280/filter-list-contained-in-entity-returned-by-jpa-hibernate-query)

Comment: that depends on your application constraint, if your application can allow a ViewModule has a "hidden" parent, then the above won't work. however if the constraint is enforced somewhere in your application, then the above query should work

Comment: i think this should be the solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300280/filter-list-contained-in-entity-returned-by-jpa-hibernate-query

Comment: yeah. I used the filter in a wrong way. I disabled the filter directly after caling query.getResultList(). This had the effect to disable the filter on the children's lazy initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new collection and add only the elements that have `hide=false`. You won't be able to distribute that collection together with the object, so you'd have to return it from a separate method call. For example: `dao.getVisibleItems(module)`

Another thing - you can remove the Cascade.DELETE (i.e. list all cascades except delete) and the orphan removal, if you don't need them.