# JPA Join Column with where condition OR filter an entities with any declarative way

Tags: select, jpa, join, filter

I know there is an option in Hibernate to filter entites based on an @Filter annotation!

Is there an option for a JPA 2.0 version of this (i am interested in mainly non-programmatic way -> declarative e.g. persistance.xml option or annotation option)

The goal:
In our application we want to filter all entites whose attribute `Active` is `False` or `0`.

And do not love to write 30 or more specific selects for this! 
I hope it has a more clear way to achieve this!

The perfect functionality would be `@Filter` and `@FilterJoinTable`, referenced this answer:
[Filter list contained in entity returned by jpa/hibernate query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300280/filter-list-contained-in-entity-returned-by-jpa-hibernate-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation i may say there is **no option** in JPA to get a filter function with Annotation.

The closest ones to this is:

- **Criteria API** (http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria)
- **Manual written query** (entityManager `createQuery()` or `createNativeQuery()`) for getting entites. (http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/execute)

However I think it is a missing and very needed functionality :(